# Bot discord button

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot to approve users on my discord server, and I came across this error!

my code:

```
import discord
from discord_components import Button, DiscordComponents
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import discord.ui 
from discord import ui



intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents, help_command=None)
DiscordComponents(bot)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot Ligado.")
    bot.add_view(Verify())


#----------------------------------------------------
class Questionare(ui.Modal, title="Solicitar SET"):
    qra = ui.TextInput(label="QRA:")
    patente = ui.TextInput(label="PATENTE:", placeholder="Aluno / Agente")
    
    async def on_submit(self, ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        user = interaction.user
        guild = interaction.guild
        role = guild.get_role(1073616684763578398)
        if self.patente.value == "Aluno" or self.patente.value == "aluno":
            await user.edit(nick="Aln. "+self.qra.value)
        elif self.patente.value == "Agente" or self.patente.value == "agente":
            await user.edit(nick="Agt. "+self.qra.value)
        channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(1078375134479515708) # canal de logs
        embed = discord.Embed( color=discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name="Novo Registro", icon_url="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3804/3804348.png"),
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar),
        embed.add_field(name="QRA: ", value=user.mention, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="CARGO: ", value=self.patente , inline=False)
        await channel.send(embed=embed, components = [Button(label="Aprovar", style="3", custom_id="button1"), Button(label="Negar", style="4", custom_id="button2")])
        interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        if f"{interaction.custom_id}" == "button1":
            await channel.send("botao aprovado clicado", ephemeral=True)
        if f"{interaction.custom_id}" == "button2":
            await channel.send("botao negado clicado", ephemeral=True)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Sucesso! Seja Bem-Vindo.", ephemeral=True)
#----------------------------------------------------


class Verify(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
    @discord.ui.button(label="Identifique-se", custom_id="Verify", style= discord.ButtonStyle.success)

    async def verify(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(Questionare())


@bot.command()
async def iniciar(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="INVESTIGAÇÕES PCERJ", 
        description="Para ter acesso, identifique-se abaixo.",
        colour= 14483456
        )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8d/a3/ad/8da3ad9575652bba957033720f43434f.png")

    await ctx.send(embed = embed , view = Verify())       

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

the error:
PS C:\Users\negojha\Desktop\botteste> & C:/Users/negojha/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/negojha/Desktop/botteste/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\negojha\Desktop\botteste\main.py", line 2, in 
from discord_components import Button, DiscordComponents
File "C:\Users\negojha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord_components_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from .client import *
File "C:\Users\negojha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord_components\client.py", line 12, in 
from .component import Component
File "C:\Users\negojha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord_components\component.py", line 3, in 
from discord import PartialEmoji, Emoji, InvalidArgument
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidArgument' from 'discord' (C:\Users\negojha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord_*init*_.py)
PS C:\Users\negojha\Desktop\botteste>

Comment: check this post, I think this is regarding your issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71847665/importerror-cannot-import-name-invalidargument-from-discord
Basically removed from newer version

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using `discord_components` you shouldn't import them. Also, discord.py does provide full functionality for interactions, like the view you're using, so you should rather avoid another, outdatet library.

Just remove the imports for `discord_components` and your code should work just fine.

:-)